# Table math in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Is there a way to get Onenote (2010) to do simple table math like sum the numbers in a row or column?

The calculating [math on the fly for entered text](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28961/calculate-simple-math-quickly-in-onenote/) stuff is really cool, but overkill for what I need at the moment. A simple *sum($above)* or *sum($left)* would be just fine.

Comment: My first thought was embedding an Excel spreadsheet, but that does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Table Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnguin/table-sum-toy-updated-for-onenote-2010) Add-In; it adds an extra row along the bottom with the column sums.

**Before:**

[[image: Screenshot_Before]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NexCE.png)

**After:**

[[image: Screenshot_After]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71JyW.png)

**Usage:**

Simply select the table to be summed and click the button in the Add-In tab of the ribbon strip:

[[image: Screenshot_AddIn]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cykfZ.png)

Comment: thank you! a little peculiar to have to install a 3rd party thing for this, but at least I have something that works :)

Comment: I couldn't get table sum to work at all

Comment: @dave Looks like it's not supported in 2013 or newer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The [Onetastic](https://getonetastic.com/) add-in has a macro feature and there is a macro that will let you apply functions to a column such as sum, average, etc.  It only puts the result into the cell, it doesn't update automatically if you change some values in the column.

After you install Onetastic, click on the "Download Macros" button. A dialog opens. Enter "function" in the search box.  There is a macro called "Function", select it and you'll see its details on the right. Click "Install" and the macro is installed.

Now put your cursor in the cell where you want (for example) the sum of the values in the column above the cell you chose.  Click the "Table" button which now appears in the Onetastic Macros part of the ribbon and select "function" from the list, a dialog opens from which you can select "sum", "average", etc.  Now click "OK" and the result is put into the empty cell.